# Getting ValueError: view limit minimum -36828.5706771 is less than... when creating Seaborn scatterplot with Date index

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, seaborn, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a dataframe that has four columns: Banana, Apple, Orange, Grapes that are floats with a date index.

I have written the following code:

```
import sns as seaborn
plt_groceries = sns.scatterplot(data=df)
```

Something else that I notice that is kind of weird is that if I run I get the following output:

```
df.index

DatetimeIndex(['2015-11-30', '2015-12-31', '2016-01-31', '2016-02-29', '2016-03-31', '2016-04-30', '2016-05-31', '2016-06-30', '2016-07-31', '2016-08-31', '2016-09-30', '2016-10-31', '2016-11-30', '2016-12-31', '2017-01-31', '2017-02-28', '2017-03-31', '2017-04-30', '2017-05-31', '2017-06-30', '2017-07-31', '2017-08-31', '2017-09-30', '2017-10-31', '2017-11-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-01-31',
               '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-31', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-31', '2018-11-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-01-31', '2019-02-28', '2019-03-31', '2019-04-30', '2019-05-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Date', freq=None)
```

However when I run this code I get the error described in the subject line.  I've read away that this is because my date index is in the wrong format? Is this true?  How do I change the format of an index or what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Interesting. I cannot reproduce this, it works fine for me. You can of course provide a [mcve], together with the full error traceback and state the versions of matplotlib, pandas, seaborn in use, so someone can investigate.

Comment: And actually, the last example in the [scatterplot documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) shows precisely this case and is working fine as well.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure to be honest I just tried re-running and getting the error.  Can you help me understand what the error is indicating?

Comment: The error suggests that you are trying to plot dates as well as other numbers to the same x axis. This is not backed by anything shown in the question, so I can only say that you need to create a [mcve]. First for yourself, but then also to share here in case you can't solve it alone.